# order by pid ? (asc|desc) placeholders statement

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I'm thinking that this "problem" can not be solved.
I have in my code **not short** querys.

Depending on the value of the variable, I need to sort the date by ASC or DESC.

I do not want to copypaste querys. I thought that i can work as usual variables, but it's not. (?)

How can (**whether it is possible at all**) to substitute in the query ASC or DESC, as well as variables?

```
query prepare error
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? limit ? offset ?' at line 1
```

`simply example:`

```
...
$sort='asc';
...
select pid,title_posts,txt_posts,count_postvs,usname from posts join usopt on uid_posts=uid_usopt 
where uid_posts=? and postacc=1 order by pid ? limit ? offset ?

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($rawdata, 'isii', $uid, $sort, $_SESSION['r2sh'], $offset);
...
```

---

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a conditional expression in the `order by`:

```
order by (case when ? = 'asc' then pid end) asc,
         pid desc
```

Comment: interesting... I  know so little about mysql :(